# How does a Firefox Overlay Manipulate HTML DOM?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I was able to make a toolbar button with the following..

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <toolbarbutton id="myextension-button" 
    class="toolbarbutton-1"
    image="chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/favicon.png"
      oncommand="XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.doSomething(event);"
    label="label" tooltiptext="tooltip" />
</toolbarpalette>
```

When I call the "document" object in the doSomething function, I believe its manipulating the XUL DOM, not the HTML webpage. How do I access the content of the HTML webpage in my function doSomething? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could just go:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <toolbarbutton id="myextension-button" 
    class="toolbarbutton-1"
    image="chrome://xulschoolhello/skin/favicon.png"
      oncommand="gBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML='rawr'"
    label="label" tooltiptext="tooltip" />
</toolbarpalette>
```

Instead of window inside the inline oncommand you can just do `gBrowser.contentDocument` or `gBrowser.contentWindow` to access the DOM of the browser in the current tab.

Comment: I noticed you accepted the solution. FYI gBrowser is a property on the chrome window object so really it is `window.gBrowser` but because you are already in that scope you can just go gBrowser. So just a FYI.

Comment: THANK YOU! As a new developer. Two quick questions. How the heck do you find out about something like this specifically "gBrowser.contentDocument" property. I did not come across any tutorials at all on MDN that told me about this. My second question is what if I want to inject a script called "test.js" into the current page? Once again, you are a lifesaver.

Comment: do `console.log('variable view of blah =',OBJECT_HERE)` and fill in OBJECT_HERE with like window then open up browser console and you will see a message there like `"variable view of blah" "[object ChromeWindow]"` click on the "object ChromeWindow" and it will open it up in VariableViewer and you can see every property in that object. Img [HERE](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v135/noitidart/my20code20works_zpsdd244f45.png) and [HERE](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v135/noitidart/i20dont20see20nsIInterfaceRequestor_zps7bfc9d43.png) showing example of variable view on different objects

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for the images. Any ideas for injecting scripts ('test.js') into the HTML DOM and calling a function within that script (when the button is clicked)? I'm doing this for my internship and it would be a HUGE LIFESAVER if I can do this.

Comment: Yes I absolutely have an idea in fact I did that in my addon [ghForkable](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghforkable/) just last month. I replied to your topic about that. If you want upload your addon to github invite me and ill seti t up for you. or email me.

Answer (score 1):

it definitely is in the chrome scope

```
doSomething = function(event) {
var DOMWindow = event.originalTarget.defaultView; //this should be the chrome window
//however if its not then do var DOMWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'); //make sure to import Services.jsm

var HTMLWindow = DOMWindow.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.contentWindow; //might be _linkedBrowser
}
```

Comment: What I want is for when the user clicks the toolbar button to be able to modify the document. Doesn't the keyword "window" already accesses the HTML window?

Comment: No from that scope it's the chrome xul window.